# What dynamic memory used for?(C++)

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I read about C++ dynamic memory allocation. Here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    int a[t];
    return 0;
 }
```

What is the difference between the above and the following:

```
int* a=new(nothrow) int[t];
```

Comment: Your code is not legal C++ (variable length arrays, or VLAs, are not allowed), so differences don't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic allocation:

- when you need control over when an object is created and destroyed; or
- when you need to create a local object that's too big to risk putting on the stack; or
- when the size of a local array isn't a constant

To answer your specific question: `int a[t];` isn't valid C++, since an array size must be constant. Some compilers allow such variable-length arrays as an extension, borrowed from C; but you shouldn't use them, unless you don't mind being tied to that compiler.

So you'd want dynamic allocation there, either the easy way, managed by [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization):

```
std::vector<int> a(t);
// use it, let it clean itself up when it goes out of scope
```

or the hard way, managed by juggling pointers and hoping you don't drop them:

```
int* a=new int[t];
// use it, hope nothing throws an exception or otherwise leaves the scope
delete [] a; // don't forget to delete it
```

Comment: thx man really. because in my computer its fine to compile like that.bad code huh....?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is C99-compatible array allocations, which occur on the stack and whose lifetimes are similar to other local variables.

The allocation example is a typical C++ dynamic memory allocation, which occurs from the heap and whose lifetime extends until `delete a[]` is reached--without this code the memory is "leaked". The one-of-lifetime occurs with the variable is destructed by `delete` and can occur after the current local scope has ended.